Switched to KDE plasma from Gnome, is privacy a issue?
I am new to linux and started with ubuntu gnome DE about a month ago. I wanted to try a different DE and found kde. However, I installed it for try purposes but there I found many snap related apps and other programs on the app store as installed. I do doubt privacy much and wonder how are their telemetry reputations? I wonder which one is safer to use, gnome or kde. I am really open to any other DE with that concerns.
I am using ubuntu 24.04

You appear to be seeking offt-topic opinions which are best dealt with on forums (this is a Q&A site and not a forum, https://ubuntuforums.org/ is the address of Ubuntu Forums). Kubuntu will install without snapd or any snaps, so what got installed will depend on what you actually installed which you don't specify. This site being Q&A requires a clearly defined problem, where readers can provide answers that deal with that clear/defined problem.  which is safer to use is not a clearly defined problem; see https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask

You've also tagged 3 different desktops; but only mention two of them, so how does your third desktop (Unity) relate?  Ubuntu Unity is another flavor which can install without snapd or snap packages, but you may mean something different by your mention of snap and Unity desktop.  https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic may also be useful...
